What does the surnmame Eco mean?
Umberto Eco! The great novelist, essayist, literary critic, philosopher, and semiotician. I couldn't find the meaning of his surname “Eco”. Does anyone know what this name means or its etymology?

The obvious meaning of eco in Italian is of course “echo”, and also the homonymous nymph Echo. Umberto Eco himself played on this meaning, but this is unlikely to be the origin of the surname. He said that it was the acronym of ex coelis oblatus (“offered from the heavens”), and this would be a surname some registry officer would have given to Eco's grandfather, who was a foundling. It used to be customary to give foundlings made-up surnames with meanings that were variations on “given by God”, “abandoned”, or specific places or objects (see for instance https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognomi_da_trovatelli_in_Italia).
Eco would have learnt this from one of his readers, bearing the same surname, but from a completely different area of Italy (see https://mimesisbooks.com/index.php/mim/catalog/download/67/1083/3160-1?inline=1).
Then again, someone suspects all of this was made up by Eco himself (see https://www.paolofabbri.it/saggi/eco_anagramma/).
